# If a class is creating an array of a type of another class, what is the relationship in terms of OOP? (Aggregation, Composition)

Tags: java, oop, uml

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Card[] cardChecker = new Card[2];

... some code
}
```

For example class Board is declaring an array type of Card which is a class that I wrote.
Is it Aggregation or Composition?

Comment: @Charlie, neither aggregation nor composition is related to inheritance. An array is one property in UML, usually drawn as an association end.

Comment: @JimL. You are correct, I was careless in my Googling.  I have removed the comment to avoid confusion.